# Deleting a application draft

Tags: application-development

I accidentally started submitting a click application when I meant to submit a desktop application is there a good way to delete it in the draft state?  I searched around the "Manage" menu and I tried searching around online a bit but I could not find anything.

Comment: hm, strange I can find where to delete the desktop drafts, but not the touch app.

Comment: probably a bug in myapps portal , report it :-)

Answer (score 0):

- Sign into [MyApps](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com).
- Click on the package name.
- At the very top of the Package Overview page, under the MyApps header bar, you should see:

  - Your package icon
  - Your package name
  - A rubbish bin (trash can) icon

Click the icon, click Yes on the confirmation page, and the package is gone.